# Is it safe to upload ARM-only builds for Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone, arm, smartphone

I'm soon going to release an app for Windows Phone 8.1, using Nokia's imaging SDK. However, the Nokia Imaging SDK does not support the *Any CPU* target platform, so I have to choose between building towards *x86* (for the emulator) or *ARM* (for my phone).

Is it safe to only upload an *ARM* build to the marketplace or might I lock out some users that way?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about whether phones without ARM processors exist, not programming.

Comment: I think not. It's a problem only programmers face. And I don't think there's a better Stackexchange page for this kind of questions.

Comment: Given that WP8 is yet to support anything beyond Qualcomm Snapdragon platforms, let alone beyond ARM, I think it's pretty safe to say that the number of affected users will be somewhere between zero and none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my knowledge goes, it's perfectly safe to upload ARM-only packages.

Comment: I just stumbled over a post in the MSDN forums, which states the same, i.e. that only options for WP are ARM and x86, and that x86 is exclusively for Emulators: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/92258f4b-67ec-47ed-ac3f-f5ddb16b66c4/windows-phone-8-app-submission-use-anycpu-or-arm

Comment: What kind of answer is this?